# Crash from [libstagefright.so] android::MediaCodec::dequeuePortBuffer(int)

Tags: android-mediacodec

The following crash is rare among a very large user base but it does happen with a few different devices:

```
[libstagefright.so] android::MediaCodec::dequeuePortBuffer(int)
SIGSEGV

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0x000000000010f918  /system/lib64/libstagefright.so (android::MediaCodec::dequeuePortBuffer(int)+240)
  #01  pc 0x000000000011197c  /system/lib64/libstagefright.so (android::MediaCodec::handleDequeueInputBuffer(android::sp<android::AReplyToken> const&, bool)+188)
  #02  pc 0x0000000000109f58  /system/lib64/libstagefright.so (android::MediaCodec::onMessageReceived(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+9136)
  #03  pc 0x0000000000017884  /system/lib64/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::AHandler::deliverMessage(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&)+84)
  #04  pc 0x000000000001da24  /system/lib64/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::AMessage::deliver()+188)
  #05  pc 0x0000000000018bd4  /system/lib64/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooper::loop()+572)
  #06  pc 0x000000000001571c  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+460)
  #07  pc 0x00000000000a0e5c  /system/lib64/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+140)
  #08  pc 0x0000000000014eec  /system/lib64/libutils.so (thread_data_t::trampoline(thread_data_t const*)+412)
  #09  pc 0x00000000000b0bd8  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
  #10  pc 0x00000000000505d0  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

[image]

All MediaCodec related code is in try-catch blocks. Could anyone shed some light on the possible causes of this crash?